# Formula for a very "steep" exponential interpolation?

Tags: exponential-function, graphing-functions, interpolation

I have two points in the 2D space, e.g. point A is (3, 2) and point B is (30, 20)

I want to get some points in between, aka, interpolating between A and B. But I don't want linear interpolation, I want something like exponential interpolation.

[I've found the following formula for exponential interpolation](http://www.pmean.com/10/ExponentialInterpolation.html):

$$y = c * (d/c)^{(x-a) / (b-a)}$$

Where $a$ is the starting value in the $Y$axis and b the end value in the $Y$ axis too

$c$ is the starting value in the $X$ axis and $d$ the end value in the $X$ axis too

In the example I stated above: $a = 2, b = 20, c = 3, d = 30$

Using this formula, this is the interpolation I get (I drawed a line for demonstration purposes, but I get some points)

[image: The interpolation i get]

But the curve is not very steep, I would like to have something like this

[image: The interpolation i want to achieve]

What formula should I use?

Comment: It looks like the curve you sketched is initially flat or maybe even decreasing at $A$.  An exponential curve won't do that.

Comment: I assume you mean the second one, right? I updated the question with a better curve

Comment: OK, that's better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

$$f(x) = \alpha \exp(\beta x^n)$$

Use points $A$ and $B$ to find $\alpha$ and $\beta$. For instance, $n=2$ gives a steeper curve than $n=1$.